# How do I select data-value in selenium c#?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'd like to select data-value="1", data-value="2" in dd.
but It doesn't work.
My code is

```
Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'s_dropdown arrow_down ws_100')]"))[1].FindElement(By.XPath("(//dd[@data-value=" + i + "])"));
```

Can Any body help me to select data-value?

[image]

Comment: Is there any error message you are getting?

Comment: Considering that your XPath doesn't appear in the image, it's going to be almost impossible to help you. Please give us more of your HTML and tell us what happens when you try to run your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'s_dropdown arrow_down ws_100')]"))[1]
```

This will return the second (at index 1, not 0) element found. If only one is found I would expect this to throw an null reference exception). I cant tell how many would be returned from the info you posted.

```
.FindElement(By.XPath("(//dd[@data-value=" + i + "])"));
```

This will return a child dd element with the matching data-value (whatever you have 'i' set to).

Take a look at [these selector tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors). And decide if the XPATH you have ought to be readdressed. Like, you could just look for all dd elements with data-value=1. Or if the row matters filter it to the row first, etc.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("dd[data-value='1']"));
Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//dd[@data-value='1']"));
```